how to upgrade java version on cassandra 4.0.5
I want to upgrade java version from 8 to 11 on my Cassandra cluster. How better to do this? Can I upgrade java version node by node. For example:

Stop 1 node
Upgrade java
Start 1 node

And repeat for another nodes those steps, or will I need to repair nodes after upgrade.
Now nodes:

Cassandra 4.0.5
Java 8

I will glad to your advices.

Your original steps should work just fine. There's no need to run a repair.
Simply, stop the node. Repoint/upgrade Java to Java 11, and make sure that the java -version command returns something like this:
openjdk version "11.0.21" 2023-10-17
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Homebrew (build 11.0.21+0)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Homebrew (build 11.0.21+0, mixed mode)

Restart the node, make sure it comes up, and repeat for all other nodes in the cluster.

so, I need follow next steps:

nodetool drain
nodetool stopdaemon
upgrade java to 11
restart cassandra service
It will be enough?
Why I ask you, as I know java 8 and java 11 use different garbage collector java, and not only this


Fortunately, there isn't much tuning necessary on the G1 garbage collector. Try running with the defaults, and adjust the MaxGCPauseMillis as needed.

Thank you so much
